# Installed Apache on Windows for homework, won't start: "The requested operation has failed!"

Tags: apache-2.2, php, windows-7

So I just set up Apache to do some web homework. When I go to http://localhost it says "It works!" but when I got to http://localhost/index.html (location of that page) I get "Unable to connect" error (Firefox). Same when I go to http://localhost/test.php

When I open Apache Monitor I click start and after clicking yes for UAC it says "The requested operation has failed!"

Here's the error log:

```
Starting the Apache2.2 service
The Apache2.2 service is running.
] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 17 11:16:19 2011] [notice] Server built: Sep  9 2011 10:26:10
[Thu Nov 17 11:16:19 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2496
[Thu Nov 17 11:16:19 2011] [notice] Child 2496: Child process is running
[Thu Nov 17 11:16:19 2011] [notice] Child 2496: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Nov 17 11:16:19 2011] [notice] Child 2496: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Nov 17 11:16:19 2011] [notice] Child 2496: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Nov 17 11:19:10 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Thu Nov 17 11:19:10 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Thu Nov 17 11:19:10 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Thu Nov 17 11:36:13 2011] [notice] Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Thu Nov 17 11:36:13 2011] [notice] Child 2496: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 129 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.  
[Thu Nov 17 11:36:13 2011] [warn] (OS 995)The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.  : winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.
[Thu Nov 17 11:36:14 2011] [notice] Child 2496: Released the start mutex
[Thu Nov 17 11:36:15 2011] [notice] Child 2496: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu Nov 17 11:36:15 2011] [notice] Child 2496: Child process is exiting
```

Comment: Nevermind, it turns out I used the non-thread safe version which didn't contain the dll. Thread safe version works.

Comment: See my answer here which may also resolve this issue.

http://serverfault.com/questions/69915/visualsvn-servers-apache-fails-to-start-with-tcp-port/355178#355178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the Apache **as Administrator** or **Disable the UAC**. the Apache`s thread is being restricted by the OS.

Comment: Close, I installed the wrong version of php, needed the thread-safe one or the opposite, can't remember, but you lead me to the right answer.